# TortoiseSVN - How can I checkout extra items in a custom depths checkout

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I'm running TortoiseSVN and our trunk is around 6GB.

I've initially checked out a branch and selected 'Choose Items' to select only the items that I require (custom depths).

I have discovered that I require some extra files that I did not check out on the initial custom depths checkout. I normally delete the branch and re-checkout the files. But this is becoming too time consuming as our trunk is so big.

How can I checkout extra items in a custom depths checkout.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You just right click inside your last folder where you need to do deeper checkout, from context menu click on **Tortoise SVN -> Update to revision** and you get same window as on checkout, where you under *Update Depth* can choose to update fully recursive, or choose items to update inside current folder.

Comment: When I do a 'Custom Depths' how do I stop it from removing my other items in my branch?